# Rails Dynamic Form - call controller with the SimpleForm params to update the page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, dynamic-forms

I am developing a page where the user can **create** a new *Product*.

Every Product has a *Product Model* which has some fields like `:id`, `:name`, `:description`, etc.

In this *Product* page, I have a `<select>` where the user will be able to pick a *Product Model*.
What I am wanting to do is, when the user select a *Product Model*, the page should update displaying the selected *Product Model* details.

How can one do that?

Comment: *How can one do that?* with [javascript](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, @sovalina! Could you give us a very simple example of how to do it, if possible, please? Thanks again o/

Comment: if you don't care about whether the entire page refreshes you could use button which submits the page and provides a product model id to a controller to recreate the whole page with the model info.    The javascript way is more elegant and would not require a page refresh but   it isn't so simple to implement as you need to use jquery and ajax calls to update just part of the page.

Answer (score 2):

Example of what you can do with javascript (based on a select change):

First define a route on collection, for a `ProductModel` custom method. Let's call it `find` :

```
resources :product_models do
  get 'find', on: :collection  #=>output: /product_models/find/:id
end
```

In `ProductModelsController` make the `find` method respond to js format:

```
def find
  @product_model = ProductModel.find(params[:id])
  respond_to { |format| format.js }
end
```

Assuming you have jQuery, in your `application.js` (or other custom js file you want), create the ajax call to find the product_model:

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
  $('#product_product_model_id').on('change', function(){ //<-- the id selector is returned by simple_form
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "/product_models/find/?id=" + $(this).val(),
      success: function(data) {
      },
      error: function(jqXHR) {
        console.error(jqXHR.responseText);
      }
    })
  })
})
```

In your `Product` new view, under your form, render a partial named, for example, "selected_product_model":

```
#new.html.erb
<% simple_form_for @product do |f| %>
  #... the form
  f.association :product_model
<% end %>

<div>
  <%= render partial: 'selected_product_model' %>
</div>
```

And in the partial, create the html selectors where the data will be displayed:

```
#_selected_product_model.html.erb
<p id="pm-id"></p>
<p id="pm-name"></p>
<p id="pm-desc"></p>
```

Then create your `find.js.erb` file (in views > product_models folder) to update your partial on select change:

```
# @product_model comes from the controller find#product_models
$('#pm-id').html("ID: <%= j @product_model.id.to_s %>")
$('#pm-name').html("Name: <%= j @product_model.name %>")
$('#pm-desc').html("Description: <%= j @product_model.description %>")
```

Of course, it's just a basic example of what you can do with ajax in rails, you can custom the way you want to display your data or add some conditions to prevent errors.

Comment: Hello, @sovalina. I do appreciate your answer :D. After all, I was able to do it by self generating the form html (not using the SimpleForm). \o/